# Drop Down Division

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a division, that when clicked, reveals itself and drops down below the menu, however, I can't get it to drop down the way that I need it to.  This is the first time I've really toyed around with something like this, so I'm not sure what needs to be done.

With the help of a few stack users, I've gotten the div to drop down and reveal itself just like I want, but the problem is that I have it set to an absolute position and instead of pushing the content below it down to make room for it, it just appears over whatever is below the menu.  (see screenshots)

This is the menu hidden:

[image: menu up]

This is the menu revealed:

[image]

Another problem I'm running into and I'm not 100% sure of a workaround is that I'm using a grid system, and the header division has 3 columns reserved for the logo (blur on the top left) and 9 columns reserved for the navigation menu.  The reason this is a problem is because the "menucontent" division - the one that's revealed - is in a list that's under the navigation division (9 columns).  I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'm hoping to get it to span the full 12 columns (978px) underneath.

I know this is probably hard to follow, so I'll post my css/html in a pastebin below.

-removed-

This should be everything.  I tried to cut down my CSS to the divisions that were being used in the header.  Thanks in advance for the help, Brian.

Comment: How about seeing that page alive? We cannot reproduce your PHP code and images. Provide direct URL.

Comment: Your website shows completely different in IE, Firefox and Chrome. You need to fix that first. Other than that - your login prompt appears to be shown just fine. There is nothing wrong using an absolute positioning. Please be more short and specific of how you want this to appear.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware.  As far as the login form, it shows up fine.  But I plan to have more content for other navigation links that drop down.  Such as the Hub link and Featured, etc.  So, I need the content to move down with it.  The login form is small so it happens to fit, but the other links will have images and content that won't.  So room will need to be made for them.

Comment: I'm fairly new to stackexchange network.  Is there anyway to enter a chat and talk a little more fluently?

Comment: This might help to make a bit more sense.  Here's the fiddle that does what I'm looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/QchfJ/4/  Notice how the division below the menu moves down with it.  I need the featured section/content of the page to do the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/WeL6j/12/ - But I need multiple links, such as this fiddle, for a navigation menu.

*Running to lunch.  Be back in a bit.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs should be independent one from another if you want to use slideToggle feature, otherwise applying an effect to one div will shift another.

Consistent structure is the key to solve an issue.